# Improve efficacy of Gradle Build Cache

Tags: java, gradle

I am building a Java/Spring Boot back-end application using Gradle. The application consists of 30 modules, all of them written in Java.

I am trying to utilize the Gradle build cache to get faster builds, however, I struggle with its efficacy. On consecutive builds with build caches activated, just ~60 of 240 tasks are "from cache", the remaining are rebuilt. This even happens, when there has not been a single modification to the application code between running the first and the second build. When there are modifications to source code, there'll be even less tasks that are cache hits.

I would have been expecting build cache to be able to eradicate most if not all tasks when doing a second build without code modifications. Unfortunately, I find little information about how to investigate. Is my assumption incorrect? If not, then how do I find out what's keeping the build cache from being more efficient?

Comment: Have you followed the guide in the Build Cache docs for [debugging and diagnosing cache misses](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache_debugging.html)? What tasks do you expect to be cached, but aren't? Be aware that IntelliJ [breaks Gradle Build Cache](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240111) - are you running from the command line? You can also try [enabling reproducible builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:reproducible_archives).

Comment: @aSemy: you could easily turn that into a full-fledged answer. It's likely to help OP and others in the same situation.

Comment: @aSemy thanks a lot! that is good information. The diagnosing cache misses page however depends on gradle enterprise to find the issues, which we are not using. any idea how else I could find out what the issue is?

Comment: @Matthias: you don't need Gradle Enterprise to use build scans, they are free to use AFAIK. *However* many companies won't be happy to use them, as they send many details about potential internal builds to a third-party with the only "security" being that the build id can't be guessed. I.e. it's a potential source for leaking internal details. If you work for a company, make sure you are allowed to use that first.